# How do I decide which experimental design to use in order to properly analyse the collected data?

Tags: experiment-design, split-plot

I'm struggling to understand which experimental design I should use. I used factorial design in most of my experiment but i recently read a document where it mention that the precision of some main effects in split-plot and strip-plot designs are sacrificed. I'm confused.

Comment: The experimental design comes first, then you perform the experiment and collect the data as defined by the design.  If you started as a factorial design, I would analyze it as a factorial design and not attempt to shoehorn it to become a split-plot design

Comment: Assume I chose split-plot design and collected my data. I then performed ANOVA to examine the main effect and interactions. So now is the question, I read somewhere that by doing so, i.e. performing ANOVA on the collected data from my split-plot design, the main effects are sacrificed. If this is the case, why do anyone want to choose split-plot design in the first place? I can't choose factorial design as it is more expensive to do field experiment plus it's near impossible to find an identical plot.

Comment: I believe you answered your your own question here.  Performing a completely random full factorial can be expensive and impractical.  The nature of a split plot design is that it is a nested designed.   Depending on how the experiment is arranged some uncounted/uncontrolled factors may confound with the main treatment.  Thus the question, during design, is what can I afford to do versus the risk of not collecting the critical results.

Comment: Is there any advice you can provide to reduce the risk?